# BaseCamp API Forbidden on PUT and POST using bearer token authorization header

Tags: oauth-2.0, omniauth, basecamp

GET requests work fine.

I am using omniauth-basecamp and restclient:

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new(
  'https://basecamp.com/27xxxxx/api/v1',
  headers: {
    user_agent: 'MyApp (me@example.com',
    authorization: "Bearer #{my_token}",
    content_type: "application/json"
  }
)

resource['/projects/7213xxx/todos/129851xxx.json'].get # => 200 OK
resource['/projects/7213xxx/todos/129851xxx.json'].put(content: 'Hello!') # => 403 FORBIDDEN
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the payload wasn't serialized as json so it was form encoded.

```
   payload = {content: 'Hello!!'}.to_json
   resource['/projects/7213xxx/todos/129851xxx.json'].put(payload) # => 200 OK
```

Wondering if the response should be Bad Request instead of Forbidden.